# javascript:void(0) not accepted by W3C, how to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, w3c

Making a link with

```
javascript:void(0)
```

violate the W3C standard.

I need to have a

```
 <a href="">
```

in my code that is not clickable and pass the W3C norms. Please don't tell me to just remove the a link because I need it for my menu and the class is important.

How could I make a link that goes nowhere and it's W3C friendly ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use this onclick event, which does exactly the same as void(0)

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Something</a>
```

Comment: This idea is particularly good. If your clients don't even have javascript, you can make them go to link that has been put in the `href`.

Comment: Yeah that works great and it's cross browser compatible. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

So long as there's not any scrolling on your page, why not

```
<a href="#" id="yourDeadA">

document.getElementById("yourDeadA").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //run your code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Because it reloads the page. I don't want to.

Comment: @Warface - I don't think that reloads the page - it just scrolls to the top of it

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine :

```
<a href="#"></a>
```